# Implementing authentication flow with react-navigation and redux

Tags: react-native, redux, react-navigation, redux-saga

I do't know what is happening here. I made simple app with 2 screens, on login success i want to change screen on HomePage. I am using redux, redux-saga and axios with react-native

My submit function on login screen is:

```
async submit() {
    if(this.state.email.length == 0 || this.state.password.length == 0) {
       alert("Filed is required")
     } else {
        if(typeof this.state.email !== 'undefined') {
            if(!this.state.email.match(/[^@]+@[^.]+\..+/)) {
                alert("E-mail format wrong!")
            } else {
                console.log('ok auth');
                let user = {
                    email: this.state.email,
                    password: this.state.password
                }
                this.props.login(user)
            }
        } 
    }
}
```

Login saga write token in `AsyncStorage`, on login success and it works fine

```
export function* loginUser(action) {
    const response = yield call(login_api, action.payload)
    if(!response || !response.data) {
        console.log('wrong login 1: ', response);
        //status 422 Unprocessable Entity
        return yield put(login_failure('Internal server error for login user'))
    }
    if(response.status === 200) {
        deviceStorage.saveItem('token', response.data.token)
        return yield put(login_success(response.data, response.data.token))
    } else {
        console.log('wrong login 2');
        return yield put(login_failure('Error for login user'))
    }
}
```

On login success, reducer returns token i `Login.js` and then I want to redirect in HomePage. I want to logout user every time when he comes on login page, because I use componentDidMount()

```
async componentDidMount() {
    await deviceStorage.deleteToken('token')
}

componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    console.log('enxtProps: ', nextProps.token.length);
    if(nextProps.token.length > 0) {
        //TOKEN EXISTS!!! length = 365
        this.props.navigation.navigate('HomePage')
    } else {
        console.log('Error login');
    }
    this.setState({
        token: nextProps.token
    })
}
```

`this.props.navigation.navigate('HomePage')` in `componentWillReceiveProps` doesn't redirect on `HomePage`.
Can someone tell me why?

Comment: **await deviceStorage.deleteToken('token')** is a api call to delete token??

Comment: yes, remove token... await AsyncStorage.removeItem('token')

Comment: So you are sure that token exists! If you are try to navigate to the page other than `HomePage`!

Comment: .If you remove token from **AsyncStotage**. so there is no props changed in your component. ComponentWillReceivedProps only called. When props has been change that's why your are not navigating to home page.

Answer (score 0):

I have a couple of suggestions for your code.

1. In Login-Saga wait until token saved

```
        deviceStorage.saveItem('token', response.data.token)
```

change to

```
        yield deviceStorage.saveItem('token', response.data.token)
```

2. Don't use componentWillReceiveProps. It is marked as unsafe in react & remove after version 17. Use componentDidUpdate as below.

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
  // Typical usage (don't forget to compare props)
  if (this.props.token !== prevProps.token && this.props.token.length > 0) {
    this.props.navigation.navigate('HomePage')
  } else {
    console.log('Error login');
  }
}
```